# How to use for loops as a substitute for recursion?

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, recursion

So I am trying to create a code that uses a for loop as opposed to recursively calling the function but if I have a integer n as a parameter to my function, I don't know how to get it to subtract 1 from itself.

For example, I want my function to have two parameters, a string s and an integer n and I want it to simply print s*n, and do it over and over again until n=0.

Like: 
wordwordwordword
wordwordword
wordword
word

If this makes any sense I would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
def funcName(strr, numm):
    while (numm != 0):
        print(strr*numm)
        numm -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop backwards from n:

```
def supercopy(word, n):
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        print word * i
```